# Shadowplay records wrong monitor

Tags: monitor, shadowplay

I have 2 monitors (1920x1080), and I run Battlefield 4 on my second monitor (secondary screen). When I try to save background recording in Shadowplay (1 min video), it always saves the desktop image from my first monitor (primary screen).

How can I force Shadowplay to record the secondary screen instead of the primary screen? I don't want to play on my primary screen.

Comment: I tried to find something in google, but word 'shadowplay' in search query results in excessive amounts of irrelevant results.

Comment: Since Shadowplay is still a beta it may be this sort of thing isn't available (and may be it won't ever be, as many responses would just be "play on primary display"). There doesn't seem to be a setting for it.

Comment: I solved it by changing primary monitor in settings, but I still curious if there is another way.

Comment: Same issue here. I really think that they just never thought about a user gaming on a secondary monitor. But I'm sure with enough interest they will most definitely upgrade the software to support secondary capture.